# python3 points to non-existant version

Tags: gnome-terminal, python3

Firstly, excuse my ignorance. I'm a Windows user needing to build a C program for a Linux server, and I know little about the inner workings.

Nothing is executing in my terminal, and the Gnome terminal won't even open. The mistake is my `/usr/bin/python3` file reads `python3 -> /usr/bin/python3.4` using `ll`.

Python 3.4 doesn't exist - I need to change that to Python 3.5, which does exist.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: How did you manage to mess that up in the first place? If gnome-terminal doesn't open, try `xterm`.

Comment: @muru raises a good point. However you managed to break that, what else might be broken?

Comment: The command `gnome-terminal.real` should open up GNOME Terminal. The upstream project doesn't depend on python, it's an Ubuntu modification that a wrapper command is inserted in front of the binary which you skip this way.